# R lattice: add text to a scatterplot on x-axis considering grouping

Tags: r, scatter-plot, lattice

I have a data set with values `y`at two dates `x`for two groups `gp`. Additional I have for each of these values a figure `n` which I would like to add at the x-axis. Here is the code to produce the data and the figure:

```
set.seed(1234)
data0 <- expand.grid(gp = c("A","B")
                  , x = 1:2
                  )
data0$y <- round(runif(4),2)
data0$n <- round(100*runif(4),0)
data0

#   gp x    y  n
# 1  A 1 0.11 86
# 2  B 1 0.62 64
# 3  A 2 0.61  1
# 4  B 2 0.62 23

xyplot(y ~ x | gp, data=data0
       , panel = function(...) {
           panel.xyplot(...)
           panel.text(1,0.1,86)
           panel.text(2,0.1,64)           
       }
       )
```

And here is the the figure:

[image]

I would like that the correct `n` are on the x-axis that is: n should be added at the x-axis considering the grouping `gp` and `x`.
Any idea how to cope with this?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "at the x-axis." Do you want the numbers at y=0.1 like you showed, but with the correct values of n for each panel? Or do you want to replace the labels on the x-axis (1,2) with the values of n? Or do you want the values of n below the x-axis labels? Or?

Comment: @DaveTurek The first one. For example, for each mean value `y` at each year `x` (1,2) I want to know how many patients (`n`) have been measured for `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subscripts` to keep track of each row in your panel functions.

```
xyplot(y ~ x | gp, data=data0,#subscripts=TRUE,
       panel = function(x,y,subscripts,...) {
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
           panel.text(data0$x[subscripts],0.1,data0$n[subscripts])
       }
)
```

You might want to adjust where you put the text (y=0.1) to avoid almost overplotting the data.

(EDIT: commented out `subscripts=TRUE` which isn't necessary here.)

Comment: That's it. Sincerly, I like lattice but for me it is more difficult to understand the syntax.